# Django URL pattern for an unusual address

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Which regular expression do I write in my URLs to give me this 'host:8000/**?page=1**' in my browser address

Answer (score 3):

None. You don't write regular expressions for query string parameters. You get them in views with

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

Comment: I need a pattern to get  (?page=1) like r'^?page=(?p<num> \d{1})/$' ,but this doesn't work in URLs . [page = request.GET.get('page') ] just gives you value of page object

Comment: i bro. Look : host:8000/ <<<<----- it is home page. Now you want to get ?page=1 this meaning that you want to filter you home page and this meaning that in you urls you don't want specific url for it. you want to check in you view Get param like page.